# Select2 create duplicate tags list outside input

Tags: jquery-select2

How to create [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhhBs.png) tags list outside?
And each tag must have possibility do unselect itself.
P.S. For example, use default style of select2. No special code needed from me.

Comment: Please include a minimal complete example in your question. People may not want to click weird-looking links.

Comment: Added embed image, sorry